# How to change the selected option in the web page using AngularJS for Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

My purpose is to make a drop down select with options from 0 to 9 digits. I'm actually composing 4 such  modules together and running calculations. Now I met problem on reset the 4 selects into a default state after user accidentally selected options that can not be posted to the backend.

```
<select ng-init="q8_1_selected" ng-model="q8_1_selected" ng-change="q8_select_digit_1(q8_1_selected)" ng-options="item1 for item1 in q8_digit_array">
                        {{item1}}
</select>
```

I have this simple select code using Angular, now I can get the q8_1_selected value with $scope.q8_1_selected no problem, however when I set the value like

```
$scope.q8_1_selected = 1;
```

This is not updating the selected option on the web page. What's wrong?

q8_digit_array is [0..9], a digit array.

Just tried,

```
<option ng-selected="item1 == q8_1_selected">{{item1}}</option>
```

to replace {{item1}}, but after `$scope.q8_1_selected = 1;` it still not changing anything on the web page. After removing ng-init, still not working.

**Update:**
**It is just the web page not updating.**

Maybe I should show the whole picture, I'm actually using Ionic, which uses AngularJS for all the bindings.

```
 <select class="q8_select" ng-model="q8_1_selected" ng-change="q8_select_digit_1(q8_1_selected)" ng-options="item1 for item1 in q8_digit_array">
                        {{item1}}
 </select>
```

js,

```
//change function, I have total 4 like this one.
$scope.q8_select_digit_1 = function(digit){
        $scope.q8_1_selected = parseInt(digit) ;
        q8_update_answer() ;
      }
//each time the answer must be calcluated
 var q8_update_answer = function(){
        var n1 = $scope.q8_1_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_2_selected ;
        var n2 = $scope.q8_3_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_4_selected ;

        //!!!!---- Problem happens here, the following changes on $scope.q8_1_selected etc. Sometimes working, but most of the time, not updating the web page ----!!!!
        //However the value of $scope.q8_1_selected and all others are correct. The data is binded, at the JS side. 

        if (n1 == 0){
          $scope.q8_1_selected = 0 ;
          $scope.q8_2_selected = 1 ;
        }
        else if (n2 == 0){
          $scope.q8_3_selected = $scope.q8_1_selected ;
          $scope.q8_4_selected = $scope.q8_2_selected ;
        }
        else if (n2 < n1){
          $scope.q8_3_selected = $scope.q8_1_selected ;
          $scope.q8_4_selected = $scope.q8_2_selected ;
        }

        n1 = $scope.q8_1_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_2_selected ;
        n2 = $scope.q8_3_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_4_selected ;

        $rootScope.answerData[$scope.whichQuestion-1] = [n1,n2] ;


      }
```

Comment: what are your options in `q8_digit_array` ? Try to set one of the array value in `$scope.q8_1_selected = array_value` instead `$scope.q8_1_selected = 1; `

Comment: q8_digit_array  is an array like from 0 to 9, as digit.

Comment: Try `$scope.q8_1_selected = true;`

Comment: why you're having `ng-init="q8_1_selected"` ? Please try without this.

Comment: @Vineet, removed, still not working

Comment: @Emidomh, q8_1_selected is a digit, it can't be true I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite excited that I just met one of the most important gotcha in AngularJS. Please have a look here ['the always dot practice'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768720/921082). And this [official document](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). And a [video presentation.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) What I had to do is to add the dot in all the `ng-model` directives.

So the data model must be changed to,

```
 var q8_result = [0,1,0,1] ;

      $scope.q8_s_obj = {
        q8_1_selected: q8_result[0],
        q8_2_selected: q8_result[1],
        q8_3_selected: q8_result[2],
        q8_4_selected: q8_result[3]
      } ;
```

And the html,

```
<select class="q8_select" ng-model="q8_s_obj.q8_3_selected" ng-change="q8_select_digit_3(q8_s_obj.q8_3_selected)" ng-options="item3 for item3 in q8_digit_array">        
     {{item3}}            
 </select>
```

The ng-change,

```
$scope.q8_select_digit_3 = function(digit){   
  $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_3_selected = parseInt(digit) ;
  q8_update_answer() ;
}
```

And finally the update function,

```
var q8_update_answer = function(){
        var n1 = $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_1_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_2_selected ;
        var n2 = $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_3_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_4_selected ;

        if (n1 == 0){
          $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_1_selected = 0 ;
          $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_2_selected = 1 ;
        }
        else if (n2 == 0){
          $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_3_selected = $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_1_selected ;
          $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_4_selected = $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_2_selected ;
        }

        else if (n2 < n1){
          $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_3_selected = $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_1_selected ;
          $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_4_selected = $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_2_selected ;
        }

        n1 = $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_1_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_2_selected ;
        n2 = $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_3_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_s_obj.q8_4_selected ;

        $rootScope.answerData[$scope.whichQuestion-1] = [n1,n2] ;

        //$apply() will not work here, if it must be there, it can be the new evalAsync(), but it hasn't to be there, this is not need to be explicit.
        //$scope.$evalAsync() ;

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I write answer in order to avoid flood in comment.

This should works :

```
<select ng-init="q8_1_selected" ng-model="q8_1_selected" ng-change="q8_select_digit_1(q8_1_selected)" ng-options="item1 for item1 in q8_digit_array" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
                        {{item1}}
</select>
```

Then :

```
$scope.q8_1_selected = 'YES'; // checked

$scope.q8_1_selected = 'NO'; // unchecked
```

You can put whatever you want in `ng-true-value="'YES'"` and `ng-false-value="'NO'"`.

According your need, as I understand, you can put digit instead.

**EDIT :**

Try this :

**html**

```
 <select class="q8_select" ng-model="q8_1_selected" ng-change="q8_select_digit_1()" ng-options="item1 for item1 in q8_digit_array">
                        {{item1}}
 </select>
```

**js**

```
//change function
    $scope.q8_select_digit_1 = function(){
      $scope.q8_1_selected = parseInt($scope.q8_1_selected) ;
      q8_update_answer() ;
    }
    //each time the answer must be calcluated
    var q8_update_answer = function(){
      var n1 = $scope.q8_1_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_2_selected ;
      var n2 = $scope.q8_3_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_4_selected ;

      //!!!!---- Problem happens here, the following changes on $scope.q8_1_selected etc. Sometimes working, but most of the time, not updating the web page ----!!!!
      if (n1 == 0){
        $scope.q8_1_selected = 0 ;
        $scope.q8_2_selected = 1 ;
      }
      else if (n2 == 0){
        $scope.q8_3_selected = $scope.q8_1_selected ;
        $scope.q8_4_selected = $scope.q8_2_selected ;
      }
      else if (n2 < n1){
        $scope.q8_3_selected = $scope.q8_1_selected ;
        $scope.q8_4_selected = $scope.q8_2_selected ;
      }

      n1 = $scope.q8_1_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_2_selected ;
      n2 = $scope.q8_3_selected * 10 + $scope.q8_4_selected ;

      $rootScope.answerData[$scope.whichQuestion-1] = [n1,n2] ;
      $scope.$apply()

    }
```

Not sure but if it's still not working, it might be due to some async troubles...

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I have 10 digital values in the options, I 'm confused 'yes' or 'no' will work in my case ?

Comment: @tomriddle_1234 Yes, it should. In your function `q8_select_digit_1(q8_1_selected)` which is in your ng-change, you set somewhere 'yes' or 'no' value to select or not the option. Maybe you can also try to put `$scope.$apply()` to update changes on the view, but it's not suppose to be a requirement according my knowledge..

Comment: I updated my code, thank you so much, but I'm still confused.

Comment: I have an idea, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506864/ionic-select-does-not-update-function-dependent-on-scope-variable.

Comment: @tomriddle_1234 I edited my post, take a look and tell me if behaviour improved or not. :)
Edit : Which error ?

Comment: Sovled, check my own answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
<select ng-model="q8_1_selected" ng-change="q8_select_digit_1(q8_1_selected)" ng-options="item1 for item1 in q8_digit_array"></select>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.q8_1_selected = $scope.q8_digit_array[1];
```

**UPDATE**

I guess you don't need to make a function which trigger on `onChange` of select. Each time value change, it automatically assigns in `q8_1_selected` model. If you're going to manipulate, then you could direct user `$scope.q8_1_selected` and it will contain the selected option. I hope it may help with the code. :)

Comment: I think you might not be right, if I remove the ng-change, the q8_1_selected is not updated in my case

Comment: Because you're using `ng-init` for the same model too.

Comment: In the code above, I already removed ng-init. My problem is actually the ng-model value is correct, but it is not bind to the web page.

Comment: There are many ways to show the changes on views. You can go through `ndDirective`. In such cases you can tell angular forcefully to apply the changes to show on the view. Actually in your case angular doesn't know whether the variable is changed. You can use `$scope.$apply()` in such cases. It throws error, if it will be used in between the ongoing process. Let me know what error are you getting ?

Comment: Sovled, check my own answer. Thank you!